# "return52" is invalid for the specified symbol(Google Spreadsheet + Google Finance)

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

On using  [GoogleFinance](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) macros in Google Spreadsheet , **"return"** attributes for 1,4,13,52 week return provides the following error:

```
Code :   
    =GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","return52")

ERROR:
    Function GOOGLEFINANCE parameter 2 value is invalid for the symbol specified.
```

However other attributes like **"price"** work fine:

```
Code :   
     =GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price")
    
Response: 146.83
```

Is there any alternate way to access these attributes?

Answer (score 1):

`AAPL` is a stock and as mentioned on the documentation for [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en):

> attribute is one of the following for mutual fund data:
>
> - "return52" - Fifty-two-week (annual) total return.

You can check on the following stack exchange post to know how this can be done:

[How can I get GoogleFinance to see 1 year and 5 year return of a stock?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95230/how-can-i-get-googlefinance-to-see-1-year-and-5-year-return-of-a-stock)